# Performance issues jsonb in Postgres

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, database-performance, postgresql-9.4, jsonb

I have some performance issue with jsonb in postgres. I have quite a lot of products in my db and each has one column called technical_details, which saves all the technical details each like this

```
{ 
    detail: {
        unit: unit_name,
        value: value 
    }
}
```

e.g:

```
{ 
    weight: { 
        unit: ‘kg’,
        value: 1000 
    } 
}
```

Now I would like to make a query like the following:

```
Product Load (149.4ms) 
    SELECT "products".* FROM "products" 
    WHERE (COALESCE(CAST( nullif(technical_details#>>’{weight,value}','') AS FLOAT),0) BETWEEN 500 AND 1500)
```

But as you can see it takes a really long time to make such a query. Does someone have an idea how I could improve the performance of such a query?

Thanks so much!

**Edit:** 
As Dmitry requested:
These are the indices I have which are related to technical details:

```
"index_products_on_technical_details" gin (technical_details)
"index_products_on_technical_details_width" btree ((technical_details ->> 'width'::text))
"index_products_on_technical_details_weight" btree ((technical_details ->> 'weight'::text))
```

This is the `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` query:

```
Seq Scan on products  (cost=0.00..926.80 rows=22 width=1288) (actual time=0.100..30.563 rows=498 loops=1)
   Filter: ((COALESCE((NULLIF((technical_details #>> '{weight,value}'::text[]), ''::text))::double precision, 0::double precision) >= 500::double precision) AND (COALESCE((NULLIF((technical_details #>> '{weight,value}'::text[]), ''::text))::double precision, 0::double precision) <= 1500::double precision))
   Rows Removed by Filter: 3997
 Planning time: 0.236 ms
 Execution time: 30.740 ms
```

Comment: "really long time" is not very precise description. Could you please provide your indexes configuration (`\d tableName`) and `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` output ?

Comment: With ' really long time' I was referring to the Product load time of 149.4ms which is given in the Rails console. I improved the question with the requested info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a expression-based index to speed it up:

```
create index on products (
  COALESCE(CAST(nullif(technical_details#>>'{weight,value}','') AS FLOAT),0)
);
```

Of course it is a bit odd to look at values which might not all be in the same unit.